# Simple question about the definition of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have a question concerning the definiton of Brownian motion. Usually (e.g. on Wikipdia) one demands a brownian motion $\lbrace B_t\rbrace_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ to satisfy the following condition:

$\forall 0\leq t_0<t_1<...<t_m: B_{t_1}-B_{t_0},...,B_{t_m}-B_{t_{m-1}}$ are independent random variables.

But today I come across with formally another definition of Brownian motion! Instead of the above condition the book demands the following property:

$\forall t,h\geq 0$, $B_{t+h}-B_t$ is independent of $\lbrace B_u : 0\leq u\leq t \rbrace$.

Now I'm wondering whether both properties are indeed equivalent or not?! Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are indeed equivalent.

**Proof:** Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ arbitrary random variables and denote by

$$S_j := \sum_{k=1}^j X_k$$

the $j$-th partial sum. Since $$X_j = S_j - S_{j-1} \qquad \quad S_j = \sum_{k=1}^j X_k$$

it is not difficult to see that

$$\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = \sigma(S_1,\ldots,S_n).$$

If we set $X_j := B_{t_j}-B_{t_{j-1}}$ for a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$, then this shows

$$\sigma(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_n}) = \sigma(B_{t_1}-B_{t_0},\ldots,B_{t_n}-B_{t_{n-1}}). \tag{1}$$

Consequently,

$$\begin{align*} \sigma\{B_u; u \leq t\} &\stackrel{\text{Def}}{=} \sigma \left( \bigcup_{\substack{t_1<\ldots<t_n \leq t \\n \in \mathbb{N}}} \sigma(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_n}) \right) \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{=} \sigma \bigg( \underbrace{\bigcup_{\substack{t_1<\ldots<t_n \leq t \\n \in \mathbb{N}}} \sigma(B_{t_1}-B_{t_0},\ldots,B_{t_n}-B_{t_{n-1}})}_{=:\mathcal{G}} \bigg). \end{align*}$$

Since $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\cap$-stable generator of $\sigma(B_u; u \leq t)$, we conclude that $B_{t+u}-B_t$ is independent from $\sigma(B_u; u \leq t)$ if, and only if, $B_{t+h} -B_t$ is independent from $\mathcal{G}$. And this is equivalent to $B_{t+h}-B_t$ being independent from $B_{t_n}-B_{t_{n-1}},\ldots,B_{t_1}-B_{t_0}$ for all $t_1 < \ldots < t_n \leq t$.

**Literature:** See e.g. *René L. Schilling/Lothar Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes* (Lemma 2.14).

Comment: could you clarify the last paragraph, right after you conclude that $B_{t+u}-B_t$ is independent from $\sigma(B_u; u \leq t)$ if and only if $B_{t+u} -B_t$ is independent from $\mathcal{G}$. Now, one needs to argue that $B_{t+u}-B_t$ is independent from $\sigma(B_u; u \leq t)$ if and only if $B_{t_m}-B_{t_{m-1}},\ldots,B_{t_1}-B_{t_0}$ are independent for all $0 \leq t_1 < \ldots < t_m $.

Comment: @Holden94 If $B_{t_m}-B_{t_{m-1}},\ldots,B_{t_1}-t_0$ are independent for all possible choices of indices, then my calculation shows that $B_{t+u} - B_t$ is independent from $\mathcal{G}$ and hence from $\sigma(B_u; u \leq t)$. On the other hand, if $B_{t+u}-B_t$ is independent from $\sigma(B_u; u \leq t)$ it is not difficult to see that the increments are independent. For this you can use for instance characteristic functions, i.e. show that $$\mathbb{E} \exp \left( i \sum_{j=1}^m \xi_j (B_{t_j}-B_{t_{j-1}}) \right) = \prod_{j=1}^m \mathbb{E}\exp(i \xi_j (B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_j})).$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I deleted my question as this seems to answer it. May I ask what $\cap$-stable generator means? Does it mean generating $\pi$-system?

Comment: @user661541 Yes, it does. $\mathcal{G}$ is called a $\cap$-stable generator of a sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ if $\mathcal{G}$ is stable under intersection (i.e. $F,G \in \mathcal{G} \implies F \cap G \in \mathcal{G}$) and $\mathcal{G}$ generates $\mathcal{F}$ (i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal{G}) = \mathcal{F}$).

Comment: I did not understand your comment: if $B_{t_m}-B_{t_{m-1}}, \dots, B_{t_1}-B_{t_0}$ are independent, then your calculation shows that $B_{t+u}-B_t$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$. How exactly does your calculation show that? Thanks.

Comment: @user661541 I showed that $\sigma(B_u; u \leq t)$ is generated by $$\mathcal{G} := \bigcup_{0<t_1 < \ldots<t_n \leq t, n \in \mathbb{N}} \sigma(B_{t_1}-B_{t_0},\ldots,B_{t_n-}-B_{t_0}).$$ Consequently, $B_{t+h}-B_t$ is independent from $\sigma(B_u; u \leq t)$ if (and only if) $B_{t+h}-B_t$ is independent from $\mathcal{G}$. Because of the definition of $\mathcal{G}$, this is in turn equivalent to $B_{t+h}-B_t$ being independent of $B_{t_1}-B_{t_0},\ldots,B_{t_n}-B_{t_{n-1}}$ for any choice of $0<t_1 < \ldots <t_n \leq t$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it!