# Show that $\sigma(X_s; s \leq t)=\sigma\left( \bigcup_{\substack{t_1<\ldots<t_n \leq t \\n \in \mathbb{N}}} \sigma(X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n}) \right) $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ be a stochastic process. Then $$\sigma(X_s: s \leq t) :=\sigma \left( \bigcup_{s \in [0,t]}{} \{ \sigma(X_s) \}\right).$$

Now, why is it the same as 
$$ \sigma(X_s; s \leq t) = \sigma \left( \bigcup_{\substack{t_1<\ldots<t_n \leq t \\n \in \mathbb{N}}} \sigma(X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n}) \right) $$

which I found here [Simple question about the definition of Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918943/simple-question-about-the-definition-of-brownian-motion). Can someone show it rigorously?

Comment: Hint: Double inclusion.

Comment: I think I got it.